# nng to pynng communication is not working

Tags: python, c, nanomsg, pynng

I am trying to make a c-program server that publishes images via nng, and a python client via pynng that subscribes to the images.

For some reason i cannot connect these 2 parts and I dont know why. C/C++-program compiles and runs fine and so does python program, but something is published on the C/C++-program, nothing is recieved on the python client. Client and server runs on the same machine. Here is my C/C++-code for the server:

```
#include <nng/nng.h>
#include <nng/protocol/pubsub0/pub.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    nng_socket sock;
    int rv;
    const char *url = "tcp://0.0.0.0:2234";

    if ((rv = nng_pub0_open(&sock)) != 0) {
            fatal("nng_pub0_open", rv);
    }
    if ((rv = nng_listen(sock, url, NULL, 0)) < 0) {
            fatal("nng_listen", rv);
    }

    // camera setup code omitted

    while(1){
        INT r = IS_SUCCESS;
        char* frame =(char*) d.processNextFrame(50,r); // grab image. if not successful, continue loop
        if (r != IS_SUCCESS || !frame)
            continue;

        std::cout << "frame caught... "<< bpp * nImgW * nImgH<< std::endl;

        if ((rv = nng_send(sock, frame, bpp * nImgW * nImgH, 0)) != 0) {
            fatal("nng_send", rv);
        }else{
            std::cout << "Frame Sent... "<< std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my python code for the client:

```
from pynng import Sub0, Timeout
address = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:2234'
sub2 = Sub0(dial=address, recv_timeout=5000)
print(sub2.recv())
```

Can someone help me understand why this is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to subscribe to topics on your subscribing socket, or you won't receive anything.  In order to receive all messages, subscribe to the empty string:

```py
from pynng import Sub0, Timeout
address = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:2234'
# note the additional keyword argument, topics:
# =============================================
sub2 = Sub0(dial=address, recv_timeout=5000, topics=b'')
print(sub2.recv())
```

Here are the pynng docs for [`Sub0`](https://pynng.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core.html#pynng.Sub0).

I'm the creator of pynng.  It would probably be nice to be clear in the docs that not subscribing to anything means you'll never receive anything; this is a common point of confusion.

Comment: Hi, i see that works if i set sub2 = Sub0(dial=address, recv_timeout=5000, topics=b'')

But only if i send a simple message like this:
std::string tstdata("msg");
if ((rv = nng_send(sock, (void*)tstdata.c_str(), 3, 0)) != 0)

If i send the large array as shown above it does not work. Should i add something additional to make that work?

Comment: How large is "large"?  nng used to drop messages larger than 1 MB by default, and I can't remember if the latest pynng keeps that behavior.  More recent nng releases allow any message by default now, and future pynng will too.

Comment: You can set `recv_max_size` to `0` on the sub socket to accept any size of message.

Comment: i am trying to send 5044624 bytes per message

Comment: So setting `recv_max_size = 0` on the sub socket should solve that issue.

Comment: Maybe it would be a good idea to show in a warning that the message is discarded instead of silently discarding it?

Comment: This has been discussed on the [nng issue tracker](https://github.com/nanomsg/nng/issues/954) and led to a new default, which is to *not drop messages*.  pynng just hasn't been updated yet :-).  I remember losing a lot of time the first time I hit this problem with the legacy nanomsg library.  Oh, the pain.